# Triggering error condition for AngularJS $http promises?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

So I have a service defined as follows:

```
angular.module('services', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('Things', function ($rootScope, $http) {
    var basePath = 'rest/things/';
    return {
        getAll: function () {
            return $http.post($rootScope.PAGES_URL + basePath + 'getAll/' + window.clientId, {});
        }
    };
});
```

Then, elsewhere, I'm consuming that service w/:

```
Things.getAll().success(function(things){
  //do something w/ things
})
.error(function(err){
  // Clearly, something went wrong w/ the request
});
```

What I'd like to do, is be able to "throw" the error condition if, for instance, there's a problem w/ the data at the service level. i.e.:

Data comes back as:

```
{
  status:500,
  message:'There was a problem w/ the data for this client'
}
```

And so then in the service there would be something like:

```
getAll: function () {
        return $http.post($rootScope.PAGES_URL + basePath + 'getAll/' + window.clientId, {})
  .throwError(function(data){
    return (data.status && data.status == 200);
  });
}
```

So when the throwError callback returns false, the error() promise would then be called instead of the success promise.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Create a deferred in your service. Actually hook into the **success** and **error** callbacks for the `$http` call. Inside the **success**, check the `status` property of the response; if it isn't in the `200` range, **reject** the deferred. Otherwise, **resolve** the deferred. **Reject** anything in the **error** callback. And return the deferred's **promise** from the service method

Comment: Ian, thanks.. can you give a code example as an answer?

Also, should I maybe use an interceptor for this?

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http

Comment: If you're sure that all requests will follow this convention, then using an interceptor definitely makes more sense. You can create the interceptor like in the example on that page, and inside the `response` callback, check if the response's property, `status`, and if it's "bad", use `$q.reject(response);`, otherwise `return response || $q.when(response);`

Comment: Ok... but on that page it says to attach the factory for the interceptor to $provide.  In my example above, can I just chain it onto my 'services' module?

Also, can you add your comments above into an answer so I can credit you with it? :-)

Comment: Also, is there a benefit to doing it in as a named factory as opposed to pushing it onto the http interceptors stack as is shown in the second half of the example on that page?

Comment: Yeah, you should be able to chain it onto the module! And I don't think there's a benefit between the two ways that the docs provide - I like to break things up as much as possible, so I would prefer to make it a named service. I think that way, it also makes it easier to mock/test if you wanted to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're sure that all requests will follow the convention where the data returned from a response includes a **status** code, then using an HTTP Interceptor makes sense. To do this, you can create a service and push it to the interceptor list for the `$httpProvider`:

```
.factory("myHttpInterceptor", function ($q) {
    return {
        response: function (response) {
            if (response.data.status && (response.data.status === 500)) {
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
            return response || $q.when(response);
        }
    };
});
```

You could replace the `=== 500` with something like `>= 400` to handle all errors, not just a 500.

And inside your module's `.config()`, add this:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push("myHttpInterceptor");
```

**References:**

- `$http` interceptors: [description](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http#description_interceptors)